# Rasterize a shapefile to match an existing raster

Tags: gdal, batch, gdal-rasterize

I want to work with ecoregions (described in the shapefile from https://ecoregions2017.appspot.com/) in combination with a digital elevation model, to generate a least-cost path. For that purpose, it seems very useful to convert the ecoregions shapefile into raster tiles that match my DEM.

It looks like I can get the srs info from the DEM by running

```
gdalsrsinfo -o wkt /vsizip/elevation/GMTED2010/GMTED2010S30W060_150.zip/30s060w_20101117_gmted_med150.tif > GMTED2010S30W060_150.wkt
```

and then rasterize the shapefile around there by

```
gdal_rasterize -l Ecoregions2017 -te -30 -60 -10 -30 -ts 7200 4800 -a OBJECTID -a_nodata 999 -a_srs GMTED2010S30W060_150.wkt -ot UInt16 -of GTiff /vsizip/ecoregions/Ecoregions2017.zip /tmp/ECOREGIONSS30W060_150.tif
```

However, extracting the `-te -30 -60 -10 -30` from somewhere in a batch process sounds like a pain (and the `-ts` should also be available from the TIFF). How can I use the metadata contained in `30s060w_20101117_gmted_med150.tif` to automatically set the extent for this batch process?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe easier to to just "clip" the raster with the shapefile?

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff \
    -cutline myshapefile.shp \
    -crop_to_cutline \
    /vsizip/elevation/GMTED2010/GMTED2010S30W060_150.zip/30s060w_20101117_gmted_med150.tif \
    clipped_file.tif
```

If your shapefile extends several TIFF tiles you can just add the filenames to the call (I'm repeating it here because can't be bothered making it up :-D), and it'll mosaic **and** clip.

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff \
    -cutline myshapefile.shp \
    -crop_to_cutline \
    /vsizip/elevation/GMTED2010/GMTED2010S30W060_150.zip/30s060w_20101117_gmted_med150.tif \
    /vsizip/elevation/GMTED2010/GMTED2010S30W060_150.zip/30s060w_20101117_gmted_med150.tif \
    clipped_file.tif
```

In Python...

```py
import gdal
files = ["/vsizip/elevation/GMTED2010/GMTED2010S30W060_150.zip/30s060w_20101117_gmted_med150.tif",
"/vsizip/elevation/GMTED2010/GMTED2010S30W060_150.zip/30s060w_20101117_gmted_med150.tif"
]
shp_file = "myshapefile.shp"
g = gdal.Warp("clipped.tif", files, format="GTiff",
             cutlineDSName=shp_file,
             cropToCutline=True)
g = None
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various tiny tools out there to help extract extent information from gdalinfo. [CMCDragonkai](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/5b039b14406035d5f8645e430b06bd1a) suggests the shell one-liner (with some cleanup after it)

```
gdalinfo /vsizip/elevation/GMTED2010/GMTED2010S30W060_150.zip/30s060w_20101117_gmted_med150.tif | grep 'Lower Left\|Upper Right' | sed -E 's/[^\(]+\(([^,]+),([^\)]+)\).+/\1 \2/' | paste --serial
```

With those extents stored in variables, the batch conversion boils down to

```bsh
 for zip in ../elevation/GMTED2010/*.zip
 do
     # Get the name of the relevant tif inside the zip
     file=$(unzip -l $zip | grep -o '[^ ]*med150.tif$')
     echo $file
     # Get its extent as four space-separated boundaries
     extent=$(gdalinfo /vsizip/$zip/$file | grep 'Lower Left\|Upper Right' | sed -E 's/[^\(]+\(([^,]+),([^\)]+)\).+/\1 \2/' | paste --serial)
     # Save its coordinate system to a file
     gdalsrsinfo -o wkt /vsizip/$zip/$file > GMTED.wkt
     # Output the command about to be run to the console, for debugging
     echo gdal_rasterize -l Ecoregions2017 -ts 7200 4800 -a OBJECTID -a_nodata 999 -a_srs GMTED.wkt -ot UInt16 -of GTiff /vsizip/Ecoregions2017.zip -te $extent /tmp/ECOREGIONS-${file}
     gdal_rasterize -l Ecoregions2017 -ts 7200 4800 -a OBJECTID -a_nodata 999 -a_srs GMTED.wkt -ot UInt16 -of GTiff /vsizip/Ecoregions2017.zip -te $extent ECOREGIONS-${file}
 done
```